# Woocommerce stock availability hook/filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Our stock levels are not stored in woocommerce, the problem is our distributor has our stock levels and we have to get that data using an API.

Is there a hook I can use when woocommerce checks availability and I can check with the distributor API and return the amount of stock and prevent the product being added if out of stock?

I have done some googling but had no luck.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What way are the products being added at the moment? There is an option to hide products that are out of stock.

Comment: @Howlin I dont think you have understood. All products are in woocommerce but not the stock levels.

Comment: In the `abstract-wc-product.php` file (found in woocommrece/includes/abstracts/) there is a function called `get_availability()` which deals with the ability to add an item to the cart or not. In that function you would need to query the API to see if the product is in stock or not.